# PowerShell Splatting with ValidateSet

Tags: powershell, validateset

I cannot seem to get splatting to work when a functions parameter uses a validation set.

The below example produces the following error:

> WhichFruit : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'fruit'. The
>   argument "System.Collections.Hashtable" does not belong to the set
>   "Apple,Orange" specified by the ValidateSet attribute. Supply an
>   argument that is in the set and then try the command again.

```
Function WhichFruit {
    param(
    [ValidateSet("Apple","Orange")]
    [string]$fruit
    )

    Write-Host $fruit
}

$params = @{ fruit = "Apple" }

WhichFruit $params
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use the splatting operator `@`

```
Function WhichFruit {
    param(
    [ValidateSet("Apple","Orange")]
    [string]$fruit
    )

    Write-Host $fruit
}

$params = @{ fruit = "Apple" }

WhichFruit @params
```